# Receive share file intents with Flutter

Tags: android, ios, dart, share, flutter

I searched for a way to make my flutter app receive intents from other apps, but didn't find any.

I want to **RECEIVE INTENTS** not to send them.

example:

I want to open the Gallery and click on the share button, and choose my flutter app from the menu. and then have my flutter app receive the intent with the picture (and later send it by HTTP request).

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter

Comment: There is a plugin that do the native stuff ? 
I prefer to use dart only.

Comment: @noamaghai I'd imagine it would be pretty difficult to handle all use cases in a Dart only plugin. Receiving intents is very application specific, as well as Android/iOS specific.

Comment: @YodaScholtz I think just to prevent the java part of the project from the dart developer, I mean, just to "convert" the intent from the java class into a dart class which the developer handles himself.

Comment: I'll let you know if I come across anything, until then the first comment's answer will work and doesn't delve too deep into Java. Could always use Kotlin too - much nicer ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, (Java not a problem, I know Java) but I prefer to use just dart. 
Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `flutter-share`, all info in [Github](https://github.com/d-silveira/flutter-share.git)

You won't have to meddle with java except for changing the MainActivity extends.

It is fully functional for Android, and the iOS part is currently being developed to match the Android part.

#### Update (2020):

Now you can also use `receive_sharing_intent` package. More info in [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent)

Comment: This plugin not working well on android, This has an android exceptions, Please fix it.

Comment: Hi @noamaghai, thank you very much for your feedback, 
can I please ask you to file an issue on the github page with the details of your crash, like stack trace, and how did you setup the plugin, and what did you do just before the crash, please, so that I can help you! thanks again.

Comment: Hi @dsilveira, already did that .... Please watch out about updates on your Github

Comment: I didn't get any email notification :O
I've read it, and replied, lets continue debugging over there. Thanks

Comment: @dsilveira Any ETA on the ios support? I'm looking for this for my project.

Comment: hey @Salx I'm loking for help on that front, since I haven't had the time lately to work on this plugin, can you, or do you know someone willing to step up and help with it? Otherwise, It'll just have to wait for my spare time to become reasonsble again

Comment: Does this work on iOS 14? My attempts never produce a share target on a real device.

Answer (score 2):

There's a complete & simple example here - it includes everything you need both on the native side, and on the flutter side:
https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter

Comment: Doesn't handle IOS shares.

Answer (score 1):

It is already answered but wanted to share more details on this,

Here, you can use [receive_sharing_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent) package. It is null safe & it supports the android & iOS platforms. Using this package you can receive text & multiple media files in open as well as closed applications. So it makes life easier.

For further understanding of how to receive text & multiple media files, you can go through this [link](https://youtu.be/mtGYYlK8Ofc). Also there you will get to know how to receive intent in the closed application.