# Open a file in my flutter app from outside

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-navigation

I wanted to ask if anyone knows how to handle other apps when they press share, my flutter app appears there to open that file (like when you share a pdf on ios and appears whatsapp). Don't know if it's possible. Looking for ios way, for android we have plugins

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receive share file intents with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476159/receive-share-file-intents-with-flutter)

Comment: Only works on android :(

Comment: Have a look at this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent#-example-tab-)

Comment: Cant share a pdf or a word there :/

Comment: Did you even try it? If it doesn't work then have a look at the code in the example tab and follow the same pattern to implement your customization