# content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/89aab7b2-da3d-49c7-b7b1-53a01bf34f7a need file path flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-intent

content://com.whatsapp.provider.mediaitem/89aab7b2-da3d-49c7-b7b1-53a01bf34f7a Uri giving me this path, i tried Uri.parse() and Uri.decode() both functions not are working for me.I need file path from this Uri in flutter.
The package i am using is receive_sharing_intent: ^1.4.2

and code i am using
`Uri value = await ReceiveSharingIntent.getInitialTextAsUri();`

Comment: Should this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476159/receive-share-file-intents-with-flutter) answer your question? If not, could you give more context on your question. Like adding the [use case and other helpful details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will help you a better chance of getting an answer from the community.

Comment: I am unable to get the answer, let me explain it to you: i am trying to open pdf files from my application, when i open files from file manager it gives me URI after decoding the URI i am able to get the path. but when i click a pdf file received on my WhatsApp chat it gives me a URI but after decoding the URI i am not getting the path of the file.

Comment: Could you revise your question and put all the [use case and other helpful details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [uri_to_file](https://pub.dev/packages/uri_to_file) plugin to fetch the path from `content://uri`. To use, simply parse the uri and use `toFile(uri)`

```
import 'package:uri_to_file/uri_to_file.dart';

try {
  String uriPath = 'content://com.whatsapp.provider.mediaitem/89aab7b2-da3d-49c7-b7b1-53a01bf34f7a';
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
  File file = await toFile(uri);
} catch (e) {
  debugPrint(e);
}
```